# What to use instead of LIMIT x, y if BETWEEN is not capable? Pagination

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

I have 10k forum topics. I run this query:

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM `topics` 
   WHERE category_id = '2' 
ORDER BY `last_message` DESC 
   LIMIT 2990, 10
```

This checks all rows! All rows! Even after adding index to `last_message`. `last_message` is a time() and I want to order all messages by that descending. So, what do you suggest me? Without BETWEEN, because it can't be done with that, unfortunately.

Comment: Consider a composite index on category_id and last_message rather than just on last_message

Comment: I have already put indexes on these two, doesn't help.

Comment: But I forgot to say, to test the table, I inserted only category_id = 2, so it of course will help when I have more categories

Comment: how do you know that the query checks all rows? with the EXPLAIN sentence? what's the result of EXPLAIN?

Comment: Yes, explain. And it gives all topics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a filtering condition on `category_id`, an index on `last_message` most probably won't help you much.

The query will have to traverse the index and filter the records for `category_id = 2`. Since traversing an index is more expensive than scanning the table, a `filesort` can be a more efficient solution, and `MySQL` may prefer it over the index scan (that's most probably is what is happening in your case).

Also, as **@OMG Ponies** pointed out, `MySQL` is not capable of doing late row lookups.

Assuming that your `PRIMARY KEY` column is called `id`, you need to create an index on `(category_id, last_message, id)` and rewrite your query as follows:

```
SELECT  t.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    topics
        WHERE   category_id = 2
        ORDER BY
                category_id DESC, last_message DESC, id DESC
        LIMIT 2990, 10
        ) q
JOIN    topics t
ON      t.id = q.id
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. But... I absolutely don't understand how this query works and I really would like to get it.

Comment: @hey: @OMGPonies provided a link to an article that explains it. In a couple of words, the join makes `MySQL` to skip the first `2,990` records in a more efficient way, making it not to perform some unneeded steps.

Comment: @OMG Ponies, @Quassnoi: We use joins to join two or more tables and we choose `SELECT * FROM 'TABLE'` and here we do absolutely something else, though it works, but still, I want to understand it.

Comment: @Quassnoi: Yes, absolutely. Didn't help, because he doesn't explain the query.

Comment: @hey: "He" is me, I'm the author of the article. Actually, the whole article is dedicated to explaining the query. To understand it, you need to have some background knowledge though: what is a table, what is an index and how they work together.

Answer (score 2):

To get MySQL to use late row lookups, use:

```
  SELECT t.*
    FROM TOPICS t
    JOIN (SELECT * 
            FROM `topics` 
           WHERE category_id = '2' 
        ORDER BY `last_message` DESC 
           LIMIT 2990, 10) x ON x.topic_id = t.topic_id
ORDER BY t.topic_id
```

Without `TOPICS` column details, I have to assume there is an id column that is auto_increment for the table...

You can [read more about the behavior in this article](http://explainextended.com/2009/10/23/mysql-order-by-limit-performance-late-row-lookups/).

Comment: Can you explain it a little bit, because there guy doesn't explain this query and I don't get it at all.

Comment: @hey: The derived table (alias "x") is joined back to the TOPICS table, to get the records out of the TOPICS table based on the JOIN criteria.